# Collect Indices using Java8 Collectors

Tags: scala, java-8, collectors

I have a stream of shapes

```
Stream<Shape> shapes = Arrays.asList(TRIANGLE, CIRCLE, SQUARE, SQUARE, CIRCLE, TRIANGLE, TRIANGLE).stream();
```

where `Shape` is

```
public enum Shape {TRIANGLE, CIRCLE, SQUARE}
```

how can I write a function that groups the shapes stream into a 
`Map<Shape, List<Integer>>` such that indices are collected according to the shape?

```
public Map<Shape, List<Integer>> indexedPartition(Stream<Shape> shapes) {
//code here
}
```

In current example output of the function `indexedPartition` would look like

```
TRIANGE -> {0, 5, 6} 
CIRCLE -> {1, 4} 
SQUARE -> {2, 3}
```

In Scala I would do something like

```
val indices = Stream.from(0)

object Shape extends Enumeration {
  type Shape = Value
  val CIRCLE, TRIANGLE, SQUARE = Value
}

val shapes = Stream(Shape.TRIANGLE, Shape.CIRCLE, Shape.SQUARE, Shape.SQUARE, Shape.CIRCLE, Shape.TRIANGLE, Shape.TRIANGLE)

(shapes zip indices).groupBy{ case (s, i) => s }.mapValues(l => l.map(_._2))
//res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Shape.Value,List[Int]] = Map(SQUARE -> List(2, 3), TRIANGLE -> List(0, 5, 6), CIRCLE -> List(1, 4))
```

I tried using Collectors.groupingBy in java but I can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 3):

Stream over indexes:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;


List<Shape> shapes = Arrays.asList(TRIANGLE, CIRCLE, SQUARE, SQUARE, CIRCLE, TRIANGLE, TRIANGLE);

result = IntStream.range(0, shapes.size())
        .boxed()
        .collect(groupingBy(shapes::get));
```

Comment: can you please edit your answer for `Stream<Shape> shapes`?

Comment: @ApoorvIngle you can't do it for a `Stream` - since it does not have indexes

Comment: @Eugene how about using `Streams.zip` or some similar construct to create a tuple and then collect it as what I have demonstrated in my scala snippet. Or my notion of Java Collectors.collect is totally wrong?

Comment: @ApoorvIngle I don't know scala enough to help you here, but streams in java don't have an index - you can create a stream out of a `Set`, what index would that be?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to implement a `Collector` which records the index of an element as encountered at the end of the stream processing. Of course, that number is meaningless for unordered streams and if you have size changing intermediate operations like `filter` or `flatMap`, the number will not reflect the position within the original array anymore.

```
class IndexCollector<K> {
    int total;
    Map<K,List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();

    public static <T> Collector<T,?,Map<T,List<Integer>>> get() {
        return Collector.of(IndexCollector<T>::new,
            (c,t) -> c.map.computeIfAbsent(t, x -> new ArrayList<>()).add(c.total++),
            (c1,c2) -> merge(c1, c2),
            c -> c.map);
    }
    static <T> IndexCollector<T> merge(IndexCollector<T> a, IndexCollector<T> b) {
        if(a.total == 0) return b;
        if(b.total != 0) {
            int offset = a.total;
            b.map.forEach((t,l) -> {
                List<Integer> target = a.map.computeIfAbsent(t, x -> new ArrayList<>());
                for(Integer i: l) target.add(i+offset);
            });
            a.total += b.total;
        }
        return a;
    }
}
```

which can be used like

```
Map<Shape, List<Integer>> map =
    Stream.of(TRIANGLE, CIRCLE, SQUARE, SQUARE, CIRCLE, TRIANGLE, TRIANGLE)
          .collect(IndexCollector.get());

map.forEach((shape,list) -> System.out.printf("%-9s%s%n", shape, list));
```

Comment: I thought about that too... relying on the fact that elements reach the collector *in encounter order*, but for the reasons you stated I dropped the idea. still +1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Holger.
Don't you think this is quite verbose/tedious to implement, especially when we cannot guarantee preserving the indices when we filter/flatMap. Is there a way in which we can supply an external index generator that binds with each shape element in the stream just like in the Scala?